# Password can't be blank in Rails (Using has_secure_password)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I am totally new to Rails and I know many questions already exists for this issue on StackOverflow but I tried almost all the solutions but none of the solution is working for me.

I am trying to implement authentication in my rails project using **has_secure_password** and I followed all the steps mentioned in rails documentation. 
I am getting "Password can't be blank " error message after submitting create user form even when i am inputting password and confirm password values in input box.

Please suggest if I am missing anything.

Steps which I followed are- 
1) Added below line in gem file - 
gem 'bcrypt', require: 'bcrypt'
2) bundle install
3) My model code-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  has_secure_password
end
```

4) My View code -

```
<div>
          <%= f.label :name %>:
          <%= f.text_field :name, size: 40 %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :password, 'Password' %>:
          <%= f.password_field :password, size: 40 %>
        </div>
        <div>
          <%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm' %>:
          <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, size: 40 %>
        </div>
        <div>
```

5) My Controller Code -

```
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_url,notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: What bcrypt version are you using?

Comment: 3.1.7 and even i tried it without specifying any version

Comment: Is your `user_params` whitelisting `password` and `password_confirmation?`

Comment: no ..how can i do that?

Comment: Your `user_params` method should have both `password` and `password_confirmation` passed to the `permit` method call. Will be great if you add that method to your question.

Comment: i am not redefining user_params method ..rails by default took that right? May be this is very basic question since i am very new to rails..bt how should i redefine it?

Comment: Weird. The method might have been added by some gem then. It shouldn't be a part of rails. Can you please put the following in your controller and check the result from your log? `p user_params`

Comment: I believe rails doesn't include a `user_params` method by default. You have to define it, and should/recommend be private :)

Comment: I am getting same error, when I am trying to create entry through console -                                                                                   irb(main):001:0> user =User.new(name:"neha", password: "foo", password_confirmation: "foo")
=> #<User id: nil, name: nil, password_digest: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> user.save
   (0.4ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (7.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'neha' LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  rollback transaction
=> false
irb(main):003:0> user.errors.full_messages
=> ["Password can't be blank"]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks a lot everyone for helping me.I am able to solve this issue.

I added below line of code in my Controller

```
 wrap_parameters :user, include: [:name, :password, :password_confirmation]
```

Documentation-
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

and this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the steps here: 
[See Listing 7.17](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-strong_parameters)

Sorry, haven't checked your controller and your comment :) This should do the trick

Comment: i followed the same thing..:)

Comment: password_digest should be in database table right?its there in my case too.

Comment: try placing your `private` `user_params` method on your controller, and place all the parameters you need for your user :)

Answer (score 0):

You should add the password-related fields to `user_params`.

```
def user_params
  params.require( :user ).permit( :password, :password_confirmation, :etc1, :etc2 )
end
```

Comment: I tried above solution but it's not working :( Still getting the same error. My method - def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password_digest,:password, :password_confirmation)
    end